# Is there a CR balancing system for PCs to be used as bosses against a party?

Tags: dnd-5e, cr-calculation

I want to make a PC and stick to the build but don't know what level would be appropriate.

The party are 5 players in level 3 (CR of almost 4 in the CR system).

As a level 15 PC will be way too much, how should I approach this?

- trading defensive CR for offensive CR I could use the charts in the DMG but what are the guidelines for a smart trade to create a non TPK non too easy encounter?

Comment: Can you expand on why you wouldn't use the regular CR system? All of the inputs should be straightforward to determine for a creature built as a PC...

Comment: a level 15 PC would easily kill a group of 5 PCs in level 3 even though they should be balanced with the CR system.

Comment: How did you get to a level 15 pc, and what CR did you get for it?

Comment: CR works like that: divide the PC level by 4. 5 level 3 PC have 15 together, same as a level 15 PC. The CR is a bit less than 4

Comment: I must have missed that calculation; where’s it come from?

Comment: I think we need to know exactly which calculation isn’t working for you and where it comes from. I’m with minnmass, I’m not familiar with what you’re talking about here (despite being pretty knowledgeable about CR).

Comment: I think you have some fundamental misunderstandings with how CR works in 5e that I suspect are being dragged in from previous editions.  I think if you went back and fully read through the section in the DMG about CR and encounter building, it would solve many of your problems.